# Is it easier to implement sigma delta modulator in FPGA by filter or state space model?

Tags: fpga, signal-processing

[Sigma delta modulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta-sigma_modulation) is extensively used in quantization to reduce quantization noise.

In the literature one can see different architecture for example [python-deltasigma](http://docs.python-deltasigma.io/en/latest/) to implement a modulator. One can learn the output of the modulator by implementing the filters or one can convert the problem into a state space model and design the modulator based on A,B,C,D parameters of the state space model.

The question: If we want to implement the modulator in FPGA which appraoch we should try? FPGA is always resource constraint so state-space approach or filter approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at [digital filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_filter) on Wikipedia, I would guess that using the digital filter would be easier to implement and use less resources than the state space one, specially if you do not design the state space form into having a very sparse form.

The complexity of a filter might be analyzed as how much memory it needs to work, or how many operations (multiplication, addition, exponentiation and so on) it has to do to get a result, or many other metrics.

Since you can easily design a filter using the [Direct Form I](https://www.dsprelated.com/freebooks/filters/Direct_Form_I.html) (this is a fact from signal processing, if the filter has order N it can be expressed in this form using some amount of memory and many multiplications and additions). A filter in that form can be made using \$2N+2\$ memory (data), parameters, multiplication and additions. Or design it using the Direct Form II, you will get the same filter using \$N+1\$ memory and \$2N+2\$ parameters, multiplications and additions. That itself seems easier to be done than the following state-space implementation.

In case you make a naïve implementation of the state space filter, you will use \$N^2+2N+1\$ parameters for (A,B+C,D), \$N+1\$ memories (for X) and \$N^2+2N+1\$ multiplications and \$N^2+2N+1\$ additions.

A single-input single-output filter/transfer function with the following form:

$$ \frac{Y(s)}{U(s)} = \frac{ c_1 z^3 + c_2 z^2 + c_3 z + c_4}{z^4 +a_1 z^3+ a_2 z^2 + a_3 z + a_4 }+c_0,$$
 has the equivalent representation:
$$ x(k+1) = Ax(k) + Bu(k), ~~y(k) = Cx(k)+Dx(k), $$

$$ A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 && 1 && 0 && 0\\ 0 && 0 && 1 && 0\\ 0 && 0 && 0 && 1\\ a_1 && a_2 && a_3 && a_4\end{bmatrix} ,~ B = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix},$$$$ C = \begin{bmatrix} c_1 && c_2 && c_3 && c_4 \end{bmatrix},~ D = \begin{bmatrix} c_0 \end{bmatrix}.$$

From signal and systems, you can do manipulations on all of the \$ \bar{A}\bar{B}\bar{C}\bar{D} \$ matrices that lead to some \$ ABCD \$ that is still equivalent to the same transfer function I showed before, but has some \$ A \$ very sparse. If you do manage to get the matrix \$A\$ to be very sparse you will probably be able to get something close to the controllable canonical form, the one I show on the equation above (I am from control systems not signal processing).

Since you can use \$ ABCD \$ to represent any transfer function that is proper, you can just use that matrix form and reduce a lot the amount of operations you need to use to calculate each iteration of the filter, and calculate all the state updates with just \$2N+2\$ multiplications and having \$N+1\$ memory usage.

Also, you can take a look at these implementations of filters in Verilog and see that they use mostly the filter approach, and also give some very insightful explanation of the way they designed the code for it
[github Verilog filters](https://github.com/ZipCPU/dspfilters).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am sorry to add that I forgot to mention that in my case I have a feedback and the matrix A is full, there is no '0' in the matrix A. I am trying to implement http://docs.python-deltasigma.io/en/latest/ the CRFB/CRFF structre. The question is wether CRFB/CRFF implementation or ABCD implementation is same or not from computational resource point of view.In case of sparse A I expected ABCD to be less. Would you please have a look and comment?

Comment: May I ask what you mean in the second paragraph? Did you mean that if we design ABCD propery than we can use ABCD  with the same comutational complexity as filter?

Comment: y(:,i) = C*x0 + D1*u(:,i);
    v(:,i) = ds_quantize(y(:,i),nlev);
    x0 = A * x0 + B * [u(:,i);v(:,i)]; Is the above code has same complexicity as filter implemtation as given by CRFB/CRFF as given in the http://docs.python-deltasigma.io/en/latest/

Comment: If you are trying to implement all that library in Verilog, good luck... Does that library has a way for you to design the filter in (that form you want) and then just see the very transfer function for it? Your question was not that... for that is a one-liner: if you do it right, yes, same complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Implement both (whatever you think "a filter" is), and see which is better.  State space is just a *way* to implement a filter, it isn't *different* from a filter.

Comment: The best way is probably to compute the convolution as multiplication in the frequency domain due to the very long input vectors from the large oversampling factor.

Comment: In state space representation the matrix A is NXN where N is a filter length. I assumed this to be computationaly expensive and expected this does not arise in usual filter implemenation by convolution. Any comment please.